# Safari: how to catch CSP exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari, content-security-policy

I am creating a website and I have my appropriate CSP headers set up already. In my code I have a line in the following form:

```
<object id="some_id" data="some_data" onerror="some_stuff"></object>
```

"some_data" will violate my CSP settings, so an exception will be raised. On Chrome, this will trigger the event handler, causing "some_stuff" to be run. However, this does not happen in Safari, even though the exception did get raised when I check the inspector. May I know what do I need to do to catch this CSP exception? I want to be able to run some code once this exception has been caught.

Thank you!